# Importing azurerm_linux_virtual_machine resource - Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute

Tags: import, terraform

I imported my existing azurerm_linux_virtual_machine  in terraform state file and notice that now terraform plan is removing the identity block. Then I added the identity block in my terraform code with attributes plan was removing

```
identity {
  identity_ids = []
  principal_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  tenant_id    = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  type         = "SystemAssigned"
}
```

and now its complaining

Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
Can't configure a value for "identity.principal_id": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.

Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
Can't configure a value for "identity.tenant_id": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.

Can someone please help? I also tried with different type like "UserAssigned" but that is not helping either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of these messages is that those two attributes of the `identity` object type are chosen by the provider rather than being chosen by you in the configuration. Providers typically declare attributes in this way if they are something that the remote API decides in its response, rather than something the client decides in the request.

If your goal is to make the configuration match the object you imported into the state then you need only to set the attributes that are considered by the provider to be arguments chosen in the configuration, which in this case seems to be just `identity_ids` and `type` and so you could write the following:

```
identity {
  identity_ids = []
  type         = "SystemAssigned"
}
```

As part of the producing the plan, Terraform will try to merge the arguments you specified in the configuration with the attributes already in the state and so should therefore be able to produce an identity object that matches the one already in the Terraform state, and thus avoid proposing to make a change.